Achieving complete transparency using TAP interfaces on a Linux machine
SWITCH-A ------ DEVICE A ------ SWITCH-B
Think of such a topology. In this case, I want to achieve a full transparent communication over DEVICE A. Want I mean by this is, SWITCH-B and SWITCH-A should be able to create LACP among themselves without an interception from DEVICE A. While this should be done, DEVICE A should also be inspecting the traffic in real-time. Is it doable using Linux tap ports? Because a Linux bridge does not allow such transparency. Once SWITCH-A wants to create an LACP group with SWITCH-B, it should first create an LACP group with DEVICE A, then DEVICE a should do this again with SWITCH-B. So, I want something more transparent than Linux bridge.
How to do this with TAP ports?

Why do you want this?

'cause why I shouldn't

The answer is that no, you should probably not do this; you should run LACP between switch a and device a, and switch b and device a. Linux supports LACP. There's a reason I ask, and that's because you may have some valid but obscure reason. You obviously don't - in which case the answer is don't.

I know devices that are capable of doing this. It does not have to be with TAP ports because I just thought they are reaching this level of transparency with TAP ports. It just makes sense to me. So, you should not do this i guess, but i'll give it a try. Thx

TAP is a software interface for passing packets from the TCP/IP stack to a userspace program. And possible doesn't mean it's a good idea - which is why it's interesting to know the why part.

That's not what tap ports do. They're missing one important part – they do not actually attach to a physical interface for receiving packets; rather, they act like a fully stand-alone virtual Ethernet interface.
(When you see a VM being connected to a physical Ethernet through a tap interface... that's just done by putting them both in a bridge.)
So the short answer is that you don't.
It would be doable using a regular bridge if you slightly patched the kernel to remove restrictions from the group_fwd_mask parameter.
Actual "tapping" of packets from Ethernet could be done from a program using raw sockets or using libpcap – it would be possible to write a small program that uses libpcap to get Ethernet frames from one interface and send them through the other, and vice versa.
